# PHP, Sql Server SELECT Query converting Chars

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding

I have `Sql Server version 10.50`. And `PHP version, 5.5.28.`

I have a DB with collation `Turkish_CI_AS` and there is some tables also Turkish collaction.

My problem is, When i `SELECT` some records with `PHP sqlsrv` function then put them to `while()` loop, the returning results contains Turkish characters turning it self to English Characters, for example: The record in the table is **İnsan** but when i echo my while loop its gives me **Insan**.

I did some changes in `php.ini` file and `set default encodings as Turkish:`,
`mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-9"` and `default_charset = "ISO-8859-9"`. But nothing changed.

I don't know is it sql related or php related problem, i hope you can give me some advices.

By the way, there is no problem on Sql server management studio. It gaves me right results when i run same query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use utf-8 encoding as a standard if you work with any language, I always use Arabic with English and utf-8 give me full support. You should make your database encoding utf8_general_ci, then when you insert your Turkish data you must use this query in the main insertion data function in PHP:

```
mysql_query(" SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

This will support any data with any language.

Comment: It is not mysql related problem. As i mentioned before, its Sql-server (Mssql).

Comment: Try this for SQL server  ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how i resolve my problem in my IIS server which is connecting to Mssql:
I go to

```
Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Change system locale...
```

And i changed my `Current system locale...` as `Turkish`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use these codes for adding PHP/Mysqli Turkish Language Support.

```
// Türkçe Dil Desteği
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul"); // For Default Date
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8'); // For UTF-8 Characters
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   // For All Sql Queries Set Default UTF-8
$db->set_charset("utf8");   // For All Sql Queries Set Default UTF-8
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was about Microsoft SQL Server but this answer appears to be about MySQL.